# Notification via open graph

Tags: notifications, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with adding notifications on Facebook.

According to:

`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#notifications`

I prepare request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/notifications?template=hello&href=track_123&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

but I get the response:

*Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.*

Is this request correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight problem in the above url , access token to be used is not of the user but of  your app. First you need to get your app access_token by the use of the following get call.

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
       &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
       &&grant_type=client_credentials
```

This will return you app access token which you need to use in the above url.

Hopefully this will solve your problem.